# Resolving Muliple Promise Node-JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, promise, q

I have array of promises.

```
var defered = q.defer();
// promises is a array which will have different promises
var promises = [];

q.all(promises).then(function(response){

// SUSSECCFULLY RESOLVED ALL PROMISE THEN EXECUTION COME HERE

}, function(error){

// IF ANY PROMISE FAILED THEN EXECUTION COME HERE

});
```

I want to process all promises whether they fail or they resolved.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Some Promises Fail then it will call fail function for all promises. If all promises pass than only it will call success function. How to process some fail some pass promises.

Comment: Maybe _.allSettled_ method will be useful for you. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled

Comment: Thanks That is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

**Use case 1:**

You want to handle errors to be handled separately and success on all **not called:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
 function prOne(){
   var d = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
     d.reject();
  }, 100);
    return d.promise;
  }
 function prTwo(){
   var d = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
     d.resolve();
  }, 100);
    return d.promise;
  }
  $q.all([prOne().catch(function(){ console.log('fail for one'); return $q.reject() }), prTwo()]).then(function(){
   console.log('success');
    return $q.resolve();
  }).catch(function(){
   console.log('error');
  });;
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

**Use case 2:**

You want to handle errors to be handled separately and success on all **called anyway:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
 function prOne(){
   var d = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
     d.reject();
  }, 100);
    return d.promise;
  }
 function prTwo(){
   var d = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
     d.resolve();
  }, 100);
    return d.promise;
  }
  $q.all([prOne().catch(function(){ console.log('fail for one'); return $q.resolve() }), prTwo()]).then(function(){
   console.log('success');
    return $q.resolve();
  }).catch(function(){
   console.log('error');
  });;
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Comment: Thanks Yerken For Your Precious Time..My promise array is dynamic it can have 15 promises at a time. Is there any generic solution for this.I mean itn't there inbuild method provided by q for that ... like q.all().

Comment: Sure just handle it within the promise returned to $q.all